# Determinant of a 3x3 matrix by permutation of rows in sagemaths (with CoCalc)

Tags: matrices, permutations, determinant, sagemath

In order to solve a mathematical problem, I would have liked to know how to calculate the determinant of a 3x3 matrix with permutation of rows in sagemaths on Co Calc. Here is a type of statement, the values change each time the page is reloaded, hence the interest of programming an algorithm to find the result of the exercise by changing the values of the corresponding matrix.

[image]

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Interchanging two rows changes the sign of the determinant.

Comment: $\det A = \det B$

Comment: @Raffaele is it possible to solve this in sagemath language or in python?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to show $\det A=\det B$

```
R.<a,b,c> = QQ[]
A = matrix(R, [[a,b,c],[-8,-62,-38],[15,2,55]])
B = matrix(R, [[15,2,55],[a,b,c],[-8,-62,-38]])
det(A)
det(B)
```